# How to get values when include antd Table in Form.Item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have struggled for several hours today. However, I still cannot fix this problem. I'm now using React and Ant Design Form to post data, but I cannot get any data from Form.Item if I put Table there, is there any better solution?

Below is my code:

```
 const items = [
   {
     job: 'Engineer',
     age: 20
   },
   {
     job: 'Accountant',
     age: 24
   }
 ]

 const onCreate = (values) => {
        console.log(values);
 }

 return (
    <Form layout='vertical' onFinish={onCreate}>
      <Form.Item name='jobs'>
        <Table dataSource={items} />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
 )
```

The onCreate function only prints jobs: undefined, but I would like to get items data, any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a nice sleep, I found an alternative to solve this question.

1. Create a form instance via Form.useForm()
2. Use form.setFieldsValue({ items: items})

With these two steps, we can easily pass any data into form when submit!

See simplified code below:

```
const items = [
   {
     job: 'Engineer',
     age: 20
   },
   {
     job: 'Accountant',
     age: 24
   }
 ]

 form.setFieldsValue({ items: items});
 const onCreate = (values) => {
        console.log(values);
 }

 const [form] = Form.useForm();
 
 

 return (
    <Form form={form} layout='vertical' onFinish={onCreate}>
      <Form.Item name='items'>
        <Table dataSource={items} />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
 )
```

Below is my actual use of selectable Table and Form.

---

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import Form from 'antd/lib/form';
import Table from 'antd/lib/table';
import api from 'api.js';

const FormTable = (props) => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);
  const [filteredJobs, setFilteredJobs] = useState([]);
  
  const [select, setSelect] = useState({
      selectedRowKey: jobs.filter((item) => item.chosen).map((item) => item)
  })

  const rowSelection = {
     selectedRowKey,
     onChange: (selectedRowKey, selectedRows) => {
         setSelect({
            ...select,
            selectedRowKey: selectedRowKey,
         });
         const selectedJobs = [];
         selectedRows.map((job) => {
             selectedJobs.push({...job});
         });
         setFilteredJobs(selectedJobs);
         form.setFieldsValue({ jobs: selectedRows});
     },
   };

  const onGetJobs = useCallback(() => {
      api.getJobs(id)
          .then((response) => {
              const data = response.data.results;
              const jobsData = [];
              data.map((job) => {
                  jobsData.push({
                      ...job,
                  });
              });
              setJobs(jobsData);
        })
          .catch(() => {});
   }, []);

   return (
      <>
        <Form form={form}>
           <Form.Item name="jobs">
              <Table dataSource={filteredJobs} />
           </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </>
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is possible, as the main purpose of the table component is to only render the provided data.
But anyways check [this doc](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-row-selection). They have provided an option of adding a checkbox to the table. see if you can reverse engineer it to add text field

Comment: I am not sure about that kind of use, either . However, I have tried to use <Input type="hidden" value={items} /> as a replacement to pass data into form when submit, it still not worked as expected since I have yet found a way to trigger state update without using onChange prop in <Input> component.